# no viable conversion from 'value_type' (aka 'char') to 'string' (aka 'basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> >')

Tags: c++, string, char, type-conversion

```
string convert(string name)
{
  string code = name[0];
  ...
}
```

I get "no viable conversion from 'value_type' (aka 'char') to 'string' (aka 'basic_string, allocator >')" from this line.

If I change it to:

```
string convert(string name)
{
  string code;
  code = name[0];
  ...
}
```

Then it works.
Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Class std::string (correspondingly std::basic_string) has assignment operator

```
basic_string& operator=(charT c);
```

and this assignment operator is used in this code snippet

```
string convert(string name)
{
  string code;
  code = name[0]; // using of the assignment operator
  ...
}
```

However the class does not has an appropriate constructor that you could write

```
string code = name[0];
```

You can write like

```
string code( 1, name[0] );
```

using constructor

```
basic_string(size_type n, charT c, const Allocator& a = Allocator());
```

Comment: `std::string code = { 1, name[0] };` will construct a string of length 2, the first character being `'\1'`.

Comment: @Evg You are right. I have deleted this line.