# How can I make a new c++ style string with a character from a previous string?

Tags: c++, xcode

This is the piece of code I have. I am new, but enthusiastically learning c++. I am curious to why when I try to declare a new variable `first_letter` as a string, to hold the value of my previous string variable `greetings` first letter, this error code appears.
`No viable conversion from 'std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::value_type' (aka 'char') to 'std::string' (aka 'basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> >')`

```
 int main()
    {
        std::string greetings = "hello";
        std::string first_letter = greetings[0];
        std::cout<<first_letter;
        return 0;
    }
```

I understand bit about char and how it holds characters as an integer and is interchangeable. Feel free to explain it as hard as you need, I will look up your detailed things on google as well to learn them.
Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [no viable conversion from 'value\_type' (aka 'char') to 'string' (aka 'basic\_string<char, char\_traits<char>, allocator<char> >')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30257526/no-viable-conversion-from-value-type-aka-char-to-string-aka-basic-stri)

Answer (score 1):

There is no implicit conversion from char to string. You can use the constructor

```
std::string first_letter(1, greetings[0]);
```

or

```
std::string first_letter(greetings, 0, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no implicit constructor of `std::string` that takes a `char`. However, you can construct the string from a `char` like this:

```
std::string first_letter { greetings[0] };
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/cxMzME).

Comment: Hello. This gave me a better understanding of constructors in c++. It is useful to construct you own variables with other types not able implicity. Thank you.